# PHP Pear Mail - Adding zip attachment

Tags: php, email, pear

I have searched stack overflow and I can't find the answer to my problem.

I am trying to attach a zip file as an attachment to an e-mail automatically send by PEAR mail. Below is the code that I am using:

```
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "mime.php";

$from = '<arturl@stocktaking.ie>';
    $to = '<artlemaks@gmail.com>';
    $subject ='Test stocktake summary reports' ;
    //$body = "Hello,\n\nReports for test site have been uploaded and can be accessed by logging in to http://192.168.3.44/ using the following credentials:\n\nusername:testUser \n\npassword:testPassword\n\nKind Regards,\n\n Supervisor Name";

    $text = 'Text version of email';
    $html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
    $file = 'C:/Temp/Reports'.$this->stocktake_id.'.zip';

    echo $file;
    //die();
    $crlf = "rn";
    $hdrs = array(
                  'From'    => $from,
                  'To'      => $to,
                  'Subject' => $subject
                  );

    $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

    $mime->setTXTBody($text);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($html);

    $mime->addAttachment($file,'application/zip');

    $body = $mime->get();
    $hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
                    'host' => 'DNS SERVER',
                    'port' => '465',
                    'auth' => true,
                    'username' => 'USERNAME',
                    'password' => 'PASSWORD'
                ));

    $mail =& Mail::factory('mail', $params);
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $hdrs, $body); 


    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
        echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
    } else {
        echo('<h2>Message successfully sent!</h2>');
    }
```

The code works partially. It sends the e-mail, it attaches the file, but the attached file is called "noname" with no extension. I tried echoing the $file variable to make sure that the correct file is being selected, and it is.

Any suggestions on what the problem is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide all parameters to `addAttachment` - see the documentation at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.addattachment.php

Especially the third `$name` parameter should be interesting to you.